# Borel cantelli lemma application.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For each fixed $C>0$ write 
$$A_{c}=\{x\in [0,1]:\mid x-\frac{p}{q}\mid >\frac{c}{q^3} \text{for every relatively prime pair} (p,q)\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
Prove that each $A_{c}$ is measurable and there exists $c>0$ such that $\lambda(A_{c})=\frac{1}{2}$, whre $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.

For the $A_{c}$ is measurable we can use Borel cantelli lemma. I need help how to construct second assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set A, the complement of $A_{c}$,For any fixed q, define $A^{q}$ the same way as $A$ except that q is fixed here. It’s easy to see that this set is a union of finite intervals contained in [0,1], so each $A^{q}$ is measurable, therefore $A=\cup_{q} A^{q}$, as a countable union of measurable sets, is also measurable, so is $A_{c}$. Moreover, since the number of p satisfying conditions given in the problem is at most q, so $\lambda(A^{q}) \leq \frac{2c}{q^{2}}$, hence $\lambda(A)$ is a finite increasing continuous function of variable c. Finally, notice that when c=0, $\lambda(A)=0$, hence there exists c such that $\lambda(A)=\frac{1}{2}$, and $\lambda(A_{c})=\frac{1}{2}$.